# Eclipse Java OSX debacle - May 2013

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I can't believe this problem is still around.  I struggled with this last year and after recently rebuilding my system it is still around??

- Fresh install of OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion
- Install JDK 7u21 from Oracle and set java_home and path
- echo $JAVA_HOME
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home
- Running Eclipse throws the error

  ```
  To open “Eclipse,” you need a Java SE 6 runtime. Would you like to install one now?
  ```

There are so many discussions on this but most have users going back and loading the older mac version or hacking some sym links which are both terrible ideas to me that as of now I refuse to do.

I've seen an idea to edit the eclipse.ini file to add a -vm option but that doesn't seem to work for me.  I made my eclipse.ini look like this

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/adt.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Declipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685
```

Any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of saying the generic distress word "debacle" in your title, could you revise/edit your question's title to be more clear... e.g. "can't install Eclipse on Mac with Java7"

Comment: I think the eclipse.ini format for the -vm option should be on two lines rather than one but that change didn't fix the problem either.

Comment: I've seen comments about adding the -vm to the plist.info file as well as the eclipse.ini file so I uncommented and changed the following with no success.  oops, cant paste it here.

Comment: I can't believe I am going to have to revert to installing the seven year old version of mac java 6 just so I can run eclipse.  This is why I call it a debacle michael!  The only solution for a brand new mac to run eclipse is install a seven year old java!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you solved this problem yet but I noticed that you will get the "Install java 6" prompt regardless of your Info.plist contents and the fact that you already have another version of Java installed. So, I allowed installation of Java 6 alongside the more modern Java 7 and added this to the Eclipse key in Info.plist:

```
<string>
   -vm
</string>
<string>
   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
</string>
```

My Eclipse now runs on Java 7.